# Android - Observer DB changes with GreenDao ORM

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, greendao, contentobserver

I'm using [GreenDao](http://greendao-orm.com/) in one of my android projects.
I'm trying to implement an observer/listener for when changes are done.

So far I created a static-functions basic functions (save, replace and delete) that just post an event (via EventBus), but this approach has been giving me a-lot of headaches.

Currently, I'm trying to use ContentObserver which for some reason does not work (see attached code), but I'd love you hear suggestions for other generic solutions.

observer:

```
public class DBObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public DBObserver() {
        super(null);
        Logger.e("DBObserver was initialized!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d("SOMETHING CHANGED IN DB OBSERVER");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
        Log.d("SOMETHING CHANGED IN DB OBSERVER");
    }
}
```

registration for observer (implemented on Application onCreate):

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME, null);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(TicketModelContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, true, new DBObserver());
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is exactly the problem and how are you accessing your data?

Comment: I'm using GreenDao to excess my data, and it works. My question is how to get this observer to work, so I'll be able to listen to changes in the db.

Comment: How did you get the URI??

Answer (score 0):

When you update a record in GreenDao,
you will call

```
daoSession.getYourBeanDao().update(yourBean);
```

and then use this to notify,

```
mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(YOUR_URI, null);
```

It's worked for me.